# Openshift monitoring with ManageIQ

Tags: openshift, manageiq

I am a newbie of manageiq monitoring tool. I am trying to access to Openshift with manageiq. My development environment is Windows 10 and Docker container with manageiq/manageiq:fine-1image. I made successful connection to Hawkular on localhost with typed-in real ip address of Hawkular. But in case of Openshift, I can hardly make connection of Openshift provider. The below pictures show my Openshift provider configuration on manageiq.

```
openshift host : https://api.starter-us-east-1.openshift.com 
API port : 443
Verify TLS Certificates : deactivated.
username and password : Red Hat sign in username and password
```

But it throws the the error message.

[image]

Like the connection with Hawkular, do I have to type in the actual IP address? Where can I find the IP address of Openshift cloud?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I chose the wrong menu. The correct menu is "Compute" => "Container" => "Provider" . And the configuration is shown in the below picture
[image]